# Vpn client in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, openvpn

I want to create a vpn application such as "Touch VPN" or "Hi VPN'

How to use [xamarin](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/xamarin/) to connect to vpn server using .open files in the background?

There are [several example](https://github.com/VPNht/android) source codes in Java 
But I never found any source code in xamarin c#

How can I use c# for that purpose?

Comment: You can use the same example and code convert to c# its very easy

Answer (score 1):

Please see example Xamarin.Android VPN service demo: https://github.com/luqmanhussain/XamarinAndroidVPNExample

Accodring to your several examples, you can convert java to C# code as well. There are some tips when you want to do that.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/java-developers

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which protocol you need. But if you need a custom protocol or want to develop your own protocol in .NET using Xamarin, you can see our VpnHood project, a component base VPN via NuGet packages. It is in C# and uses Xamarin to develop the client for Android.

https://github.com/vpnhood/VpnHood