# How do I access an API through a VPN using Xamarin forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a backend published to a server that only has access via VPN and I can't consume this API from Xamarin Forms as it is outside of the VPN.

I want to be able to consume this API using Xamarin Forms (for many users?). How can I do this?

Comment: You have not asked a question.  "I want" is not a question.  Please read [ask] for guidance on how to ask a question.

Comment: About VPN in Android ,having a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863899/vpn-client-in-xamarin) .

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is for bespoke application for a specific client/set of users.

You could try to setting the VPN through your phone settings before trying to use XamarinForms to connect to service.