# Connect to VLESS (VPN protocol) ic C# on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, vpn

can you please advise me how is it possible to connect to VLESS server via C# on Android? I am planning to create a VPN application based on xamarin.forms, and have encountered this problem.

> [Vpn client in xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863899/vpn-client-in-xamarin)
> This article has no solution to my question, there is no Outline protocol here

I haven't found any clear solutions on google(